# Virtual memory management in Python (2.6-2.7) - Will it reuse the allocated memory for any type of data?

Tags: python, memory-management, virtual-memory

I have a question about the virtual memory in Python.

When the process is consuming a relatively large amount of memory, it doesn't "release" the unused memory. For example, after creating a massive list of strings, let's say the list uses 30MB of memory, so the entire process takes roughly 40MB, when the list is deleted, the process still consuming 40MB, but if another list with the same amount of data is created, the process will not take more memory, because it will use the virtual memory that is available but not released to the OS.

My question is: What kind of data will reuse that non-released virtual memory? I mean, that 30MB was "taken" from the OS when I created a list of strings, and even when I delete it, the next list of strings will not take more memory from the OS as long as it fits in the 30MB. But if instead a list of strings another type of data is created, like a QPixmap (from Qt, using PyQt), will it use that 30MB originally allocated by the list of strings?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: Well, this question sounds lazy. I know I could simply test this specific case, but i want to know in theory, I don't want the answer for this "list of strings and qpixmap" specific case, but in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the C level (CPython's implementation), anything that is allocated on the heap with `malloc()` will consume memory and this memory will not be released to the OS when that memory is freed with `free()`. It will only be returned when the process dies. But when new blocks are allocated with `malloc()` they will use the freed-up memory.

(Unless the free memory is really badly fragmented and there is not enough contiguous free space in the freed-up zones to accommodate new allocations. But let's not worry about this pathological case.)

Every Python object is implemented by CPython as one or more blocks of memory allocated with `malloc()` so the answer to your question is: pretty much any piece of Python data can reuse the space that was freed by the deallocation of some other piece of Python data.

Comment: This depends heavily on the OS and C library version. I've seen Python interpreters' memory use shrinking after deallocating huge structures.

Comment: Thank you very much! @larsmans: At least in my computer, when the process is taking less than 20MB, it will release the memory, but after some amount it stops releasing (Linux 3.2, Python 2.6.6, not home now and don't know the c lib version).

Comment: Memory **usage** will shrink as the freed memory gets paged out after being unused for some time but the process' virtual memory address space will not shrink. `malloc()` implementations that can return memory to the system upon `free()` do exist but they are very rare and almost never used as the system default `malloc()` implementation. I would not expect any general-purpose CPython configuration to be using one. Are you talking about the processes' resident size or total virtual memory size?

Comment: @AlanB.: I'm not sure what exactly this depends upon (hence no answer), but yesterday I witnessed a Python interpreter growing to close to 100% memory use, failing with a `MemoryError`, and happily continuing after that with <10% memory use (according to `top`). I suspect memory is returned to the OS when, e.g., only half of it is in use.

Comment: @Celada: total VM size, *I think*. I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: OK, so it's possible I'm wrong about that or there's some trickery going on. Interesting. But, @AlanB, I think you can count on the last paragraph of my answer in any case: freed memory is available for use by any type of new Python data.

Comment: @Celada: I'm talking about the total allocated memory size for the VM. And yes, my question is answered already. Thank you. larsmans: that sounds like a memory leak or something. Anyways... Thanks you guys.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to the problem of "freeing" memory: first, getting Python to garbage collect the objects, and second, getting unused memory returned to the OS at the C level.

If you are having problems with process size growing without bounds, you are almost certainly not allowing objects to be garbage collected.  99.9% of the time (to 0 significant digits :) ) if you are trying to second-guess Python's C-level memory management, you are in a bunny hole.

Remember that in Python your objects are not even candidates to be garbage collected until there are no more live objects with references to them.  You can very easily squirrel away a reference to an object somewhere without realizing it.

There's a Python tool called [Dowser](http://www.aminus.net/wiki/Dowser) that is very helpful at finding leaks of memory caused by keeping around references to objects.  If you see your object count for a certain class growing without bounds over time.... there's your memory problem.

Good luck!